# How many possible passwords can a user select from?

Tags: combinatorics

Question: A user's password is 9 numerical digits in length. How many possible passwords can a user select from?
My Answer: The smallest possible password can be 000,000,000 and the largest possible password can be 999,999,999. Therefore there are 1,000,000,000 possible passwords to choose from.
Is this answer sufficient or is there a better way to answer this using the multiplication principle?

Comment: Oh yes you're right! But is there a different approach to this using multiplication?

Comment: You have $10$ possibilities for each position. So the answer is $\underbrace{10\times\dots\times 10}_{9}=10^9.$

Comment: I would point out that this logic doesn't work so easily for more complicated questions, say for example "how many passwords which are 9 numerical digits in length using only 0's or 9's are there?"  You would again be able to say that the smallest possible password is 000000000 and the largest is 999999999 but the answer in this different example would instead be only $2^9=512$.  For a more complete proof, you should explain *why* subtracting the lower number from the upper number gives the correct answer.